# can't start rails server in linux terminal? showing error "Read-only file system @ unlink_internal"

Tags: permission-denied

Showing

> /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:367:in
>   `delete': Read-only file system @ unlink_internal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give permission for user that you use when start your application:

```
sudo chown username . -R
```